# Issue with App Access Token

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am attempting to get a list of all people attending a public Facebook event.  I'd like to do this without requiring a Facebook login.  All of my reading through the documentation leads me to believe that all I need is an app access token using my app ID and app secret from my Facebook app.  As a result, I've made a GET request using JQuery's .get as follows:

```
$.get("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=XXXXX&client_secret=XXXXX&grant_type=client_credentials", function(access)
    {
        token = access.split("=")[1];
    });
```

After that runs, token holds the access token I was given and I noticed it's simply in a format of `APP_ID|APP_SECRET` which seems a bit odd but I have no frame of reference to work with here so I assume that's valid.

I then attempt to get a list of all people attending a public Facebook event as follows:

```
FB.api('/1375837852632231/attending/?access_token=' + token, function(attendees) 
        {
           //Do something with attendees data
        });
```

However, this request returns an error saying that I need an access token.  Specifically, it returns:

```
FB.__globalCallbacks.f1a9557984(
     {"error":
        {
          "message":"An access token is required to request this resource.",
          "type":"OAuthException",
          "code":104
        }
     }
);
```

Am I missing something here?  Again, my scenario is that I'd like to retrieve an app access token and then use that app access token to get a list of everyone attending a Facebook event that is public.

Thanks

Comment: what's the operation you are going to do?

Comment: In your place, I would for first, debug the access token to check if it gives you enough rights, you can do it here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug. I can't help you more with the info you have given

Comment: There is nothing wrong with app access which is of the format `APP_ID|APP_SECRET`, and I tried the same and was able to retrieve the data. So I would suggest you to check if the value for `token` is valid or not. Additionally use the same on [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)

Comment: You should never use your app access token in client-side code, because every user will be able to find it there.

Comment: Try: `https://www.facebook.com?client_id=[APPID]&client_secret=[APPSECRET]&redirect_uri=[http://APPURL]&scope=manage_pages,read_stream&response_type=token` to get the token